# failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 405 (method not allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, html

i write a code to load a file but i get t he following error
failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 405 (method not allowed)

**HTML**

```
<body >
<form action="" id="uploadform">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<div class="progress_bar">
  <div class="progress" id="progress">
    <span class="counter" id="counter">25%</span>
  </div>

</div>
 <script src="js/script.js" ></script>
 </body>
```

**JS**

```
let uploadform=document.getElementById("uploadform");
let file=document.getElementById("file");
let progress=document.getElementById("progress");
let counter=document.getElementById("counter");
uploadform.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("post","uploadfile.php");
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(e)
  {
   
    if(e.lengthComputable)
    {
      let percentage=e.loaded /e.total *100;
      progress.style.width=percentage + "%";
      counter.innerHTML=percentage + "%";
    }
  })
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
  xhr.send(new FormData(uploadform));
})
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
"images/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put your code into a runnable snippet that the community could test?

Comment: @karolus the code relies on (and is failing because of) a server that Stack Overflow won't be able to access.